# terminology relating to o(1)

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

If someone says, for example, "I have an algorithm that runs in time $n^2+\varepsilon$ for any constant $\varepsilon>0$", the interpretation for this statement seems to be that for any constant  $\varepsilon>0$, there is an integer $N$ such that for all $n>N$, the algorithm runs in time at most $n^2+\varepsilon$. 
This means that there is a sequence $\varepsilon_1=1/2$, $\varepsilon_2=1/4$, $\varepsilon_3=1/8$, etc along with associated integers $N_1 \leq N_2 \leq N_3 \leq...$

But does this not mean that the algorithm is $n^2 +o(1)$?

Comment: The example seems odd. I have never seen anything like it … After all, there is usually a constant in front, so the running time is big-O of something. But $O(n^2+\varepsilon)$ is the same as $O(n^2)$, which makes me wonder if they don't *really* mean to say $O(n^{2+\varepsilon})$. That, at least, is a sort of estimate one comes across frequently. But if what you wrote is really what they wrote, then yes, your analysis seems correct.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen supposing it was $O(n^{2+\varepsilon})$, would the argument fail because the hidden constant factor could increase?

Comment: Usually $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ means $O(n^a)$ for every $a\gt2$. And no, this does not imply $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(n) = O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.  Then $g(n) = f(n)/n^2 = O(n^\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$; that is, for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find $M_\epsilon, C_\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$
0 \leq g(n) \leq C_\epsilon n^\epsilon \qquad \text{for } n \geq M_\epsilon
$$

if we assume that $g(n) \geq 0$ for $n$ large enough.  If we further assume that $g(n) \geq 1$ for $n$ large enough then we can find $N_\epsilon > 0$ such that

$$
0 \leq \log_n g(n) \leq \log_n C_\epsilon + \epsilon \leq 2\epsilon \qquad \text{for } n \geq N_\epsilon.
$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we must have $h(n) = \log_n g(n) = o(1)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now $g(n) = n^{h(n)}$, so we can write $g(n) = n^{o(1)}$ and hence $f(n) = n^{2+o(1)}$.

It should be noted that the assumption that eventually $f(n)/n^2 \geq 1$ is sufficient but not necessary to obtain this result.

---

We can obtain a slightly weaker statement using $O$ if we only assume that $f(n) \geq 0$ eventually, which I assume is the case you will be encountering when analyzing algorithms.

Let $N_1$ be the set of all $n$ such that $g(n) \geq 1$, and let $N_2$ be the set for which $0 \leq g(n) < 1$.  Then

$$
g(n) \leq n^{\hat{h}(n)},
$$

where

$$
\hat{h}(n) = \begin{cases}
\log_n g(n) & \text{if } n \in N_1, \\
0 & \text{if } n \in N_2.
\end{cases}
$$

By the argument above we have $\hat{h}(n) = o(1)$ as $n \to \infty$, so we can write $g(n) \leq n^{o(1)}$.  Thus

$$
f(n) \leq n^{2+o(1)} \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty,
$$

or if you prefer, $f(n) = O(n^{2+o(1)})$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: OK, so if the complexity is bounded by $C_\epsilon n^\epsilon=n^{\log_n C_\epsilon+\epsilon}$ then we can let $\epsilon=\epsilon(n) \rightarrow 0$ arbitrarily slowly meaning $c_{\epsilon}$ rises arbitrarily slowly, slow enough such that $\log_n C_\epsilon=o(1)$. Hence we do indeed have $n^{o(1)}$.

Comment: Epsilon doesn't depend on $n$, though.  I don't really follow what you mean.

Comment: You say "Since $ϵ$ was arbitrary we must have $h(n)=log_n g(n)=o(1)$ as n→∞." so you are implicitly saying we choose a sequence of epsilons which go to zero with $n$, because you are bounding g(n) by a function of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Hmm, I am not saying that, explicitly or implicitly.  I am using the definition of "limit", which makes no reference to a sequence of epsilons.  The $\epsilon$ in $C_\epsilon$ is fixed at the beginning, and if you're now looking at these $\epsilon(n)$'s (which I suppose are just $\epsilon(n) = \log_n g(n)$?) then they are fundamentally distinct from from it.

Comment: Yes I know you are using the definition of a limit.  The definition of a limit implies that we can define a sequence of epsilons get progressively closer to zero, and which make a step function that bounds the function log g (or what ever), which means it gets closer to zero as well. // I am saying $log_n g(n)≤log_n C_\epsilon+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon=\epsilon(n)$

Comment: I really don't get what point you're making.

Comment: It's not important. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Haha, okay :).  Glad I could help.